# How to use ChartJs in Phaser Game

Tags: javascript, chart.js, phaser-framework

I want to show stats in Phaser with some charts, and I'm using chart.js.  I have a problem and one question

1. **problem:** I'm trying to load a generated Chart.js base64Image in phaser, but it is not showing. Am I missing something?
2. **question:** Is it somehow possible to draw the chart.js on the phaser canvas? Because I would like to have the chart animation in the game, if possible.

**Here is a mini Demo, showing what I tried:**
*(with a demo chart generation)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

// Chart Generation Helper function for DEMO
function generateChart(callback){
    let data = {
        // labels: ['Highscore'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [{y: 100, x: '01.01'}, {y: 80, x: '04.01'}, {y: 130, x: '05.01'}, {y: 110, x: '06.01'}, {y: 199, x: '08.01'},],
            backgroundColor: ['#6BFF6B'],
            borderColor: ['#6BFF6B'],
         }],
    };

    const chartConfig = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins: { legend: { display:false } },
            scales: {
                x: { 
                    title: {display: false},
                    grid: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                    ticks: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                },
                y: { 
                    title: {display: false},
                    grid: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                    ticks: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                }
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: () => { 
                    callback(chart.toBase64Image());
                }
            }
        }
 };

    let chart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('chart'),
        chartConfig
    );
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 190,
    scene: {
        create
    }
};

function create () {
    generateChart(base64Image => {
        this.textures.addBase64('chart', base64Image);
        this.add.image(10, 10, 'chart').setOrigin(0);
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  

    <div id="chart-wrapper" class="chart" style="height:170px; width:350px;">
        <canvas id="chart" ></canvas>
    </div>

<div id="phaser-example"></div>
```

Comment: Why not put the chart over top of the game canvas element? or are the charts part of the game? sorry if I misunderstand Im thinking of the charts as debug data.

Comment: @DerekLawrence Well I wanted to have a stats Screen, that the player can checkout durong the game. I didn't think of overlaying the chart over the game. That might work, I must try this _(this might even solve the animation feature I wanted)_. I thought of using the canvas / image, because I can handle all the positioning and sizing with phaser directly, so that I don't have to worry too much about browser compatibility and DOM. Thank you for your input.

Comment: phaser can handle all the dom stuff for you in game as well. But it will be overtop of the entire canvas still. But works for popup menus where you do not need in game elements over top. https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.DOMElement.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@DerekLawrence** comments, the best solution with animation is to use phaser `Phaser.GameObjects.DOMElement` *([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.DOMElement.html))*.

**here the demo working:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

// Chart Generation Helper function for DEMO
function generateChart(callback){
    let data = {
        // labels: ['Highscore'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [{y: 100, x: '01.01'}, {y: 80, x: '04.01'}, {y: 130, x: '05.01'}, {y: 110, x: '06.01'}, {y: 199, x: '08.01'},],
            backgroundColor: ['#6BFF6B'],
            borderColor: ['#6BFF6B'],
         }],
    };

    const chartConfig = {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins: { legend: { display:false } },
            scales: {
                x: { 
                    title: {display: false},
                    grid: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                    ticks: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                },
                y: { 
                    title: {display: false},
                    grid: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                    ticks: { color: '#6BFF6B' },
                }
            },
            animation: {
                onComplete: () => { 
                    callback(chart.toBase64Image());
                }
            }
        }
 };

    let chart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('chart'),
        chartConfig
    );
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 190,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
};

function preload(){
    generateChart();
}

function create () {
    let chart = this.add.dom(10, 10, '#chart-wrapper').setOrigin(0);
   // chart.setInteractive().on('pointerdown', function (){console.info(arguments)})
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  

    <div id="chart-wrapper" class="chart" style="height:170px; width:350px;">
        <canvas id="chart" ></canvas>
    </div>

<div id="phaser-example"></div>
```

**btw.:** I found the reason why the base64 image was not showing up, I failed to wait for the image to load *(the event `addTexture`)*.

```
function create(){
    ...

    generateChart(base64Image => {
        this.textures.addBase64('chart', base64Image);
    });
    
    // event triggered after texture is loaded
    this.textures.once('addtexture', function () {
        this.add.image(10, 10, 'chart').setOrigin(0);
    }, this);
}
```